# Fetching from 3 tables, with one condition on one table

Tags: sql, ms-access, join

I have 4 tables

```
Order(OrderId,OrderDate,Firm,ConsumerId)
OrderProductDetails(OrderId,ProductId,Firm,Quantity,Rate,Fulfilled,PendingQuantity) [fulfilled is boolean]
Product(ProductId,ProductName)
Consumer(ConsumerId,ConsumerName)
```

I want to fetch those orders `(OrderId,OrderDate,ConsumerName)` that are not completely fulfilled. I tried a lot, but wasn't able to make it work. The query seems simple, but I do not know how complex it is gonna be.

Comment: What did you try?, show us the query you are trying and we can give you an idea

Comment: what db engine are you using? MySQL for example does not have a `boolean` type field. EDIT: Oh, I see that `boolean` exists as a synonym for `tinyint(1)`, with `1` being true and `0` being false. Is that what you do?

Comment: You can't fetch ConsumerName from those three tables because none of those tables contains a column ConsumerName.  You probably have a fourth table, Consumer, with columns like ConsumerId and ConsumerName.  Or you need ProductName instead of ConsumerName; at the moment, the Product table is unused in your query.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Apologies sir, It should have been Consumer Table instead of Product table. I have edited it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following query should work fine.
Notes:
 1) I have renamed Order table to OrderT,
       2)Renamed Consumer -> ConsumerT

*SELECT DISTINCT OrderProductDetails.OrderId, OrderT.OrderDate, ConsumerT.ConsumerName
FROM OrderProductDetails, ConsumerT INNER JOIN OrderT ON ConsumerT.ConsumerId = OrderT.ConsumerId
WHERE (([OrderProductDetails].[Fulfilled]=0) AND ([OrderProductDetails].[OrderId]=[OrderT].[OrderId]));*

The Logic behind the query is : You want the data mainly from two tables OrderT and ConsumerT. But all data depends upon OrderProductDetails.Fulfilled and last but one is the orders which are not fulfilled only those consumer name is required.
MS Access Design view while creating query helped a lot.

Answer (score 1):

From the information that you have given, the following should work.

```
select order.orderid, order.orderdate, consumers.consumername
from order
inner join orderproductdetails on orderproductdetails.orderid = order.orderid
inner join consumers on consumers.consumerid = order.consumerid
where orderproductdetails.fulfilled = 0
```

I am assuming that you have a 'consumers' table, and that boolean 'false' is represented by the value 0.

Comment: "Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'orderproductdetails.orderid = [order].orderid
inner join consumer on consumer.consumerid = [order].consumeri'."

Comment: @Vivek: seeing as you haven't shown us the structure of the consumer(s) table, you haven't stated which database you're using and you haven't shown us your query, my answer was a generic attempt at giving you a solution. Maybe you mistyped something - you wrote above '[order].consumeri' which presumably should be [order].consumeriD.

Comment: @No'am Newman sir, I appreciate your effort. I have edited my question above. and have added the "Consumer" table. I am using Ms Access database engine. I have tried many queries, in fact also the one you just gave me, but it is not working. I doubt something other than inner join would be needed.

Comment: The table name `Order` has to be made into a delimited identifier by wrapping it in square brackets in MS SQL Server and MS Access (because it is also a keyword, as in ORDER BY).  And posting the DBMS is usually relevant.

Comment: @Vivek: whenever you get a syntax error and the cause is not clear, it is best to simplify your query as much as possible until it works, then add clauses in stages. Thus your first query would be a simple 'select order.orderid from order', your second 'select order.orderid from order inner join orderproductdetails on orderproductdetails.orderid = order.orderid' and your third would be like the second but with the added 'where' clause. If these queries work, then you have a problem with the consumer(s) table.

Comment: AFAICS, if you type everything accurately and consistently, and always enclose `order` in square brackets (`[order]`), and ensure that the table names such as 'consumer' are spelled correctly for the actual DB schema, then this should produce one line per unfulfilled product in each order with any unfulfilled products.

Comment: @Vivek: I strongly suggest that you rename your tables so that 'order' becomes 'orders' and 'consumer' becomes 'consumers'. This is more natural and also you won't have any problems with keywords.

Comment: @No'amNewman I understand sir. I thought I was following the DBMS naming conventions, but would surely follow your instructions henceforth.

Comment: @No'amNewman I went step by step, as you said. I was happy to see the queries working. Thank you !
Would follow the same now.